# Nativescript webpack bundle global vars

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Since upgrading to latest version of my Nativescript (5.0.x) with Angular (7.1) the bundle is not working properly.

I get following error when running: 
`ERROR ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Document`

It worked before by putting in my **main.ts** file the following code:

```
if (!(<any>global).Document) {
  ;(<any>global).Document = function Document() {}
}
```

On normal run like: `tns run ios` it works fine. (if I remove the code above) I will get the same error as when running the bundled version.

I tried defining the global variables using the `webpack.DefinePlugin` in the **webpack.config** file like the Nativescript team seems to have done for example with TNS_WEBPACK. When doing this the app will also fail.

Comment: Try adding declaration to global variable.

Comment: @Manoj: could you be more specific please? Which globlal variable are you refering to?

Comment: Declare the `Document` property as function on the `global` module using `reference.d.ts`

Comment: Thanks @Manoj. Well it didn't fix my problem. The problem is related to webpack reordering my imports and my globals were below the import requiring them to work. What I did is to create another file where I put all my globals and imported that file via a normal module import.